# How to set css style to asp.net button?

Tags: asp.net, css, button, aspbutton

I have a asp:Button, I used css styles with cssClass property in `asp:Button`, but those styles are not working. When I use `asp:LinkButton` those styles are working well.I don't want any themes or skins for styles.

This is my asp page:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="smallButton" Text="Sign In" runat="server" ID="submit"></asp:Button>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.smallButton 
{
  //styles
}
```

When I change asp:Button to asp:LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="Sign In" runat="server" ID="submit" CssClass="smallButton"></asp:LinkButton>
```

or

```
<span class="smallButton"><asp:LinkButton Text="Sign In" runat="server" ID="submit"></asp:LinkButton></span>
```

styles are working well. Only problem with the asp:Button control

Comment: please show us code. How do you expect us to guess what you did wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide the html that the asp.net button is generating.

Comment: Thanks everyone I found the solution and I add below that coding...

Comment: This is old, but if someone runs into this, in my case, part of the css in the class didn't work for the button, so it ignored it ignored it.  That solved it for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I Found the coding...

```
 input[type="submit"]
    {
     //css coding
    }
 input[type="submit"]:Hover  
    {
     //css coding
    }
```

This is the solution for my issue.....
Thanks everyone for the valuable answers.......

Answer (score 17):

You can assign a `class` to your `ASP.NET` Button and then apply the desired style to it.

```
<asp:Button class="mybtn" Text="Button" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mybtn
{
   border:1px solid Red;
   //some more styles
}
```

Comment: I am using the same way but this is not working for asp:Button control but this is working with asp:LinkButton and Image Button controls

Comment: @Sujanth Maybe you can try to clear the cache from the browser and try again.The code seems alright.

Comment: Careful with this. ASP.Net will overwrite the CSS field. For example if you set the button disabled the css class will be overwritten with "disabled". Use the provided setter CssClass so ASP.Net can coordinate when it sets the css classes.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `CssClass` attribute and pass a value as a css class name

```
<asp:Button CssClass="button" Text="Submit" runat="server"></asp:Button>` 

.button
{
     //write more styles
}
```

Comment: This is the asp expected way

Answer (score 9):

nobody wants to go to the clutter of using a class, try this:

```
<asp:button Style="margin:0px" runat="server" />
```

Intellisense won't suggest it but it will get the job done without throwing errors, warnings, or messages.  Don't forget the capital S in Style

Comment: Downvoted. Good luck doing maintenance / overhauls on that. With a class you will at least have a single point of change.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a button in asp.net design page like "Default.asp" and you want to create CSS file and specified attributes for a button,labels or other controller. Then first of all create a css page

1. Right click on Project
2. Add new item
3. Select StyleSheet

now you have a css page now write these code in your css page(StyleSheet.css)

StyleSheet.css

```
.mybtnstyle
{
 border:1px solid Red;
 background-color:Red;
 border-style:groove;
 border-top:5px;
 outline-style:dotted;
}
```

Default.asp

{

```
  <head> 
  <title> testing.com </title>
 </head>
<body>
 <b>Using Razer<b/>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <link id="Link1" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="Stylesheet1.css" />
 <asp:Button ID="mybtn" class="mybtn" runat="server" Width="339px"/>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could just style the input element in your css file. That is then independent of ASP.NET.

```
<form action="">
    Name: <input type="text" class="input" />
    Password: <input type="password" class="input" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
</form>
CSS
.input {
    border: 1px solid #006;
    background: #ffc;
}
.button {
    border: 1px solid #006;
    background: #9cf;
}
```

With the `CssClass` you can assign the `"input"` class to it.

Comment: But then you aren't using server controls and we're not sure if that's what the user wants here.

Comment: It's basically what everybody else here suggested.

Comment: Everyone here used server controls in their examples.  Not nitpicking, but asp.net utilizes server controls for a reason.  Granted, you could have added a runat tag to these controls and voila.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you mentioned will be applied to all buttons. You should try this:

```
input[type="submit"].someclass {
    //somestyle}
```

And make sure you add this to your button:

```
CssClass="someclass"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="mybutton" Text="Link Button" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

With Hover effects :

```
 #mybutton
        {
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 150px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #mybutton:hover
        {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000;
        }
```

http://www.parallelcodes.com/asp-net-button-css/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:Button CssClass="button" style="color:black" Text="Submit" runat="server"></asp:Button>`
```

Comment: Both the `CssClass` and `style` attributes are addressed by other answers already.