# How do I customize an asp:Button class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

How do I customize an asp:Button class?

This is like this proble: [How to set css style to asp.net button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177630/how-to-set-css-style-to-asp-net-button) but not really since the button is inherited from a cs class.

I have this bit of code in an ASPX file:

```
<div class="buttonContainer" style="clear:both;width:100%;text-align:left">
   <asp:Button ID="btnProceed" runat="server"  Text="Next" OnClick="ProceedButton_Clicked" Enabled="true" />
</div>
```

So, if I want to make the button bigger or bolder text, how would I do it?

btnProceed is defined in a .cs file like this:

```
 protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnProceed;
```

So, is there some way I can inherit a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button class and change the font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your server controls are ultimately going to render some HTML markup to the browser. So Apply a **CSS class** to your button and style it the way you want. You can use the `CssClass` property to set it.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProceed" runat="server" Text="Hi" CssClass="yourClass" />
```

And put this style in your css file which is being included in your aspx page.

```
.yourClass
{
  font-size:72px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could be able to customize any style for your button with this

```
.buttonContainer input
{
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: bold;
   /**** ETC ***** /
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set Font Size at server-side by using `btnProceed.Font.Size = FontUnit.Point(50);`