# CSS selector for ASP button text

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an ASP button with text and I am wondering if there is a way to style just the text of the asp button in css? I want to style just the text with -webkit-mask-image.

```
<span class="submitSection">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$LoginUser$LoginButton" value="Enter" id="MainContent_LoginUser_LoginButton" class="submitButton">
</span>
```

I have tried:

```
.submitButton a
{

.submitButton Text
{
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you provide the rendered HTML, rather then the ASP code? (You'll have a wider pool of answerers if you do.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177630/how-to-set-css-style-to-asp-net-button may be the same question that has already been answered.  This isn't classic ASP but rather ASP.Net from the looks of the IDs in the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "style the text" I am assuming that you mean the text within the button.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/6bjxw/)

```
.submitSection input {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: this applies the style to the whole button, I need to style just the text within the button.

Comment: What specifically are you hoping to do with the text?

Comment: I am trying to apply a webkit mask image gradient over the text, and it works with normal text if I wrap the text itself in a span. But since the ASP button has the text hardcoded in the tag itself, I cant style just the text.

Comment: That is correct. Unless you can put a span inside of it, you won't be able to.

Comment: If you give an example of what you need, I can try to duplicate it.